# MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type, even with Google API target

Tags: android, google-maps

I also get "the import com.google cannot be resolved to a type", 
and i'm not sure if it is related, but my project runs fine on Android 2.3.3 but freezes on startup on the Google API 2.3.3 and 4.0,

p.s. i have included

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Please help! thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to reference correct library at compile time. But what you describe is asking Android to use this specific library at runtime.

You need to right click your Eclipse project, Properties -> Android. In `Project Build Target` select any target with vendor `Google Inc.`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not using the Google Api for the specific Android Platform Simply checing the Appropriate Target Google API will Resolve the problem.

[image]