# Quickblox location sample not working

Tags: android, quickblox

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERVi5bKhqeI
on linux mint 16 for this sample : http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-location_users-android 
But I am getting loads of errors which I could not fix:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
LatLng cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 91 Java Problem
MarkerOptions cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 90 Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 95 Java Problem
BitmapDescriptorFactory cannot be resolved  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 92 Java Problem
The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity) is undefined   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 110    Java Problem
The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity) is undefined   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 98 Java Problem
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (MapActivity, String, int)    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 132    Java Problem
The constructor EditText(MapActivity) is undefined  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 116    Java Problem
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type MapActivity    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 59 Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 58 Java Problem
The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type MapActivity   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 62 Java Problem
GooglePlayServicesUtil cannot be resolved   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 62 Java Problem
GooglePlayServicesUtil cannot be resolved   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 67 Java Problem
ConnectionResult cannot be resolved to a variable   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 65 Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 90 Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 90 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 23 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 24 Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 49 Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 51 Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 53 Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 53 Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 54 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MapActivity must override or implement a supertype method   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 57 Java Problem
The import android.support cannot be resolved   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 11 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 16 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 17 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 18 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 19 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 20 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 21 Java Problem
The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 22 Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 205    Java Problem
CameraUpdateFactory cannot be resolved  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 203    Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 199    Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 198    Java Problem
LatLng cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 196    Java Problem
LatLng cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 196    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 203    Java Problem
BitmapDescriptorFactory cannot be resolved  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 201    Java Problem
MarkerOptions cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 199    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 199    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 159    Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 161    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a variable  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 158    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 159    Java Problem
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (MapActivity, String, int)    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 170    Java Problem
LOCATION_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 180    Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 163    Java Problem
Marker cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 166    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 156    Java Problem
SupportMapFragment cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 156    Java Problem
The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity) is undefined   MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 135    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 155    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 157    Java Problem
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type  MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 158    Java Problem
SupportMapFragment cannot be resolved to a type MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 156    Java Problem
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MapActivity    MapActivity.java    /LocSample/src/com/quickblox/sample/location/activities line 156    Java Problem
```

[image]

I did add the quickblox-android-1.1.jar file in the properties and tried to fix them using this: [MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type, even with Google API target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481925/mapactivity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-even-with-google-api-target) 
But the tutorial does not ask to do any of these though and still the errors show up..

Answer (score 0):

according to logs it seems that you haven't connected Google Maps properly. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERVi5bKhqeI) shows how to start sample with Google Map Android Api v1, now sample uses Api v2, so you should connect google play services to your project.

Here is [tuturial](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_and_configure_the_google_play_services_sdk)